# Should predictive modelling response variable be measured in time after the predictors?

Tags: classification, time-series, predictive-modeling

I am interested in modelling my dataset in a predictive way to predict the outcome (eg some event occurance) at some time in the future. I have been getting confused whether the outcome variable for each timepoint should therefore be chronologically in the future compared to the predictor variables measured for that timepoint row, so therefore the predictors relate to a future event as opposed to an event which has already occured. Therefore if the current dataset has outcome variable which relates to an event occuring within the last period of time, should this be changed so it relates to the consequent following period of time after the predictor variables were measured?

I hope this makes sense, hard to describe. I am still getting used to longditudinal analytics!